# GLSL 4.2 - Syntax error: "layout" parse error

Tags: opengl, glsl, opengl-4

So, I recently found an interesting shader and tried to compile it.

But, the GLSL compiler threw the following error:

```
ERROR: 0:50: error(#132) Syntax error: "layout" parse error
```

@ (Fragment shader)

```
#version 420

...

uint ImageAtomic_Average_RGBA8(layout (r32ui) volatile uimage3D Img, ivec3 Coords, vec4 NewVal)
{ ... }
```

Details:

- Card: AMD Radeon HD 7870 (It supports OpenGL 4.20)
- I tried both the 4.2 driver and the 4.3 beta driver.

Comment: Could you post your entire vertex and fragment shader code?

Comment: @bwroga The original code can be found [here](https://github.com/domme/VoxelConeTracing/blob/master/bin/assets/shader/VoxelConeTracing/voxelizeFrag.shader). I slightly modified the style though (It shouldn't affect anything)

Answer (score 1):

A *layout qualifier* cannot be part of the function's signature. **Section 6.1.1** of the **GLSL 4.40 Specification**  defines the following grammar for a function prototype:

> *function-prototype :* 
>   *precision-qualifier type function-name(**parameter-qualifiers* *precision-qualifier type name array-specifier, ... )*

Now, a *parameter-qualifier* can be one of

> **const** 
>   **in** 
>   **out** 
>   **inout** 
>   **precise** 
>   *memory qualifier* (**volatile**, ...)
>   *precision qualifier*(**lowp**, ...)

Consistently, **section 4.10** explicitly states:

> Layout qualifiers cannot be used on formal function parameters [..]

If you drop the layout qualifier, you should be fine. If not, it's a driver bug.

Comment: Oh wow, that fixed the error. However, when I try to pass an image variable to that function (e.g. `ImageAtomic_Average_RGBA8(VoxelFragTex_Normal, ivec3(BaseVoxel), Normal);` - Declaration: `layout (r32ui) uniform volatile uimage3D VoxelFragTex_Normal;`) the compiler throws this error: `error(#373) Invalid usage of image qualifier`. Is that related?

Comment: Does it generate the error at the line where the function is called? Or at the image declaration? Or somewhere else?

Comment: @structinf: Also, is the GitHub version your current version?

Comment: With the exception of some style modifications, yes.